# Assessing a single predictor with linear modelling

Tags: regression, linear-model

I have data that involves countries in and out of Europe, life expectancy, social support and expenditure per GDP. I want to assess how successful a single country in terms of life expectancy given its social support.

I want to make this assessment with linear modelling, however, I am unsure how I could achieve this. For example, If I want to assess Germany, my data would look like this:

```
  country     life      expenditure    social_support 
  <chr>       <dbl>       <dbl>            <dbl>   
1 GER         19.8       5267.8             91.7
```

However, I cannot fit a linear model for a single variable when only a single point exists for it. Therefore, what is the best way to assess for Germany?

A larger set of data may look like:

```
  country  life expenditure  social_support 
  <chr>   <dbl>       <dbl>   <dbl>   
1 AUS      20.8       4420.2     91.7    
2 AUT      20.2       4987.2    90.2    
3 BEL      20.2       4611.7     90.8    
4 CAN      20.2       4614.3     94.2      
5 CHE      21.2       6935.4     90.5    
6 GER      19.8       5267.8    91.7
```

Comment: "However, I cannot fit a linear model for a single variable." Why not?

Comment: @ChristianHennig because the linear model will return N/A for the standard error, t value and p value and not the estimate. Because it's difficult to assess a linear trend on a single point.

Comment: @ChristianHennig I have noticed my wording was a bit off in that sentence, so I updated it. I was wondering how I can assess the performance of Germany with linear models?

Comment: Still not clear what you want to do.  Can you include code to show the error?

Comment: @RalphWinters ```lm(life ~ social_support, data=df[country == "GER",]) ``` would not work successfully as I only have data on Germany for a single point. Therefore, I wanted to know how to properly assess the importance of life expectancy on social support for Germany with linear models.

Comment: OK. So do you have data for the other 5 counties?  or is this a hypothetical larger data set?

Comment: @Ralph I have data for 30 countries in total and they all follow the same format

Comment: OK. so say you did linear regression on all 30 countries so you were able to get a standard error and p value.  What would be your definition of success? (not a statistical term)

Comment: @RalphWinters Essentially, I wanted to know with a linear model how best to assess the importance of a single country in terms of life expectancy given its social support. A successful model would assess the importance of Germany. However, how would I produce a model to show this? as I had explained before, I cannot show this with the r-code above. Because a country would represent a single dummy variable, and each have a single data point, then the summary of a linear model would not produce any P-values, or standard errors.

Comment: @RalphWinters I think the term 'importance' is not really what I want, instead the 'performance' of Germany. Now that I think about it, its performance must be assessed relative to other countries. But I still face the problem of introducing dummy variables with a single data point.